# Aggregating data before factor analysis

Tags: factor-analysis

I have data on individual sales transactions (customer bought a soap for example) and around 30 different indicators about that sale (price of item, time spend front of item display, shelf number...). For each item that customers buys, row is inserted, so there are a lot of observations. I would like to try factor analysis to reduce all these indicators to smaller group. Hopefully they tell more what creates sales at customer level. I feel that doing FA at individual item level is too noisy, so should I aggregate data for each customer before and then use FA? This way I could also calculate extra indicators such as how much time customer spend in store overall. I’m not professional, so all help is appreciated. Thanks.

[image]

I'm hoping that I could get factors to score customers afterwards. Sorry for taking long time to respond.

Bonus question: Subcustomer field is for family (Wife buys some, Husband buys some, but only all are paid together) Should I aggregate data to that level to really get more robust factors?

Comment: Hello and welcome.  Could you post a table showing a portion of your data?  That would help people understand  your situation so they could make the most applicable suggestions.  For me, I'm not sure what you mean about inserting rows.

Comment: Your added table makes the situation much clearer.  But I'm hard pressed to think of any basis for recommending that the analysis be done at the item level or the customer level.  It doesn't seem a matter anyone could answer via statistical expertise alone.  I suspect that only you know what would be the pros and cons of each approach, and whether one, the other, or both would be valuable.  Is there any specific statistical issue on which you are seeking input?